# create Dynamic table in PHP While loop

Tags: php, html, sql

I have data from my query result like this :

```
DATE           DEPTH    LOCATION    idx
2010-08-13      0.34    SAKE RIVER  1
2010-08-13      0.35    SAKE RIVER  2
2010-08-13      0.35    SAKE RIVER  3
2016-01-30     1.463    AKE KOBE    4
2016-04-12     1.524    AKE KOBE    5
2014-05-13      1.03    AKE KOBE    6
2008-12-16     0.617    SAGEA           7
2008-08-11     1.503    SAGEA           8
2008-07-03     1.369    SAGEA           9
```

how to loop this query result to create dynamic table in one index page
like this:

```
<span>SAKE RIVER<span>
<Table>
 <tr>
<th>IDX</th>
<th>DATETIME</th>
<th>DEPTH</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  </tr>
</Table>

<span>AKE KOBE<span>
<Table>
 <tr>
<th>IDX</th>
<th>DATETIME</th>
<th>DEPTH</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  </tr>
</Table>

<span>SAGEA<span>
<Table>
 <tr>
<th>IDX</th>
<th>DATETIME</th>
<th>DEPTH</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  <td>VAL</td>
  </tr>
</Table>
```

> If add more location than it will create more table

Thankyou

sorry for my english

Comment: what if location repeated in loop?

Comment: How about using framework to do this? `GridView` is powerfull tool to manage such things. Right now there's nothing linked to `yii2` in question/code so i'm removing this tag.

Comment: If your data table is the result of a database query, then you should be able to retrieve the data you want direct via a database query before using php to rendering the table. Something like `SELECT idx, date, depth FROM database_table GROUP BY location`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the database connection and the table.

```
 while ($pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery)) {

echo '<th> '.$pickresults['username'].' </th> ';  

    echo ' <td> '.$pickresults['firstgame'].' </td> '; }
```

Comment: do include echo 'table' at the before the loop and after the loop '</table>'

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are getting this data in some array variable and my suggestion you can use foreach loop:-

```
$data = //Query to fetch data
foreach($data as $key => $value) {?>
<span><?php echo $value['LOCATION']; ?></span>
<Table>
 <tr>
<th>IDX</th>
<th>DATETIME</th>
<th>DEPTH</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $value['idx']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['DATE'];  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['DEPTH'];  ?></td>
  </tr>
</Table>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
 $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
 echo $row['location']; ?>

<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
 <td>DATE</td>
 <td>DEPTH</td>
 <td>LOCATION</td>
 <td>idx</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tdbody>
 <tr>
 <?php
 echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['depth']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['idx']."</td>";
 ?>
 </tr>
 </tdbody>
 </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps.